# Are the university's acceptance rate something trusted?

Tags: university

When universities are being compared using TOEFL or other standard exams, those numbers are trusted since they are managed by a single organization. However, when universities announce acceptance rates, are there agencies or auditors that check those numbers?

Comment: I imagine this is going to vary by country...

Comment: There are apparently [cases](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2013/01/28/bucknells-admission-raises-questions-about-how-many-colleges-are-reporting-false) of dishonesty across several key ranking components of the system U.S. News uses (including selectivity that you ask about). The article also says that colleges are responsible themselves for providing numbers, and so no external auditors exist. What a college *internally* audits is likely hard to answer in general (I assume though that they typically trust those in charge of the calculations).

Comment: It's natural to guess that standardized exam statistics would be compiled by a central organization, but they are usually supplied by the universities themselves, since they are the only ones who have databases of exactly who was offered admission or enrolled.